# Expression inside selected column name

Tags: sql, oracle, select

**Problem:** I want to get an average salary of all employees. The query itself is rather simple:
[image]

**Question:** Is it possible to move `COUNT(salary)` to selected column's title (after `AS` statement), so the name of the column will be "`Average salary of 20 employees`"? I've been trying several approaches, but none of them worked. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Screenshot you posted looks like Apex SQL Workshop. I don't know how to do it there, but - if you used SQL*Plus, then you could do something like this (not *exactly* as you wanted it, though):

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL> column cnt_emps new_value l_cnt
SQL> select count(*) cnt_emps from emp;

  CNT_EMPS
----------
        14

SQL> select avg(sal) as "Average salary of &l_cnt employees" from emp;

Average salary of         14 employees
--------------------------------------
                            2073.21429

SQL>
```

---

However, if you're already using Apex, switch to GUI and create a page which will let you format the result any way you want (using colors, large font, bold letters, whatever). SQL*Plus and its *descendants* are kind of restrictive when such things should be done.